# Understand the empirical likelihood

Tags: likelihood, empirical-likelihood

When I read the talk notes by Owen about empirical likelihood,

http://www.ms.uky.edu/~mai/sta709/Owen2005.pdf

I am confused about the solve of solution when I read the page 24.

Let's say we want to get the maximum value of $\sum_{i=1}^n \log(n w_i)$ with the constrained condition, to solve the optimisation problem, we need to specify $\lambda$, and it should satisfy the following condition:

$0 = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i - \mu}{1 + \lambda (x_i - mu)}$,

then my question is that, for some cases, obviously we have more than one $\lambda$ will satisfy the condition and what we should do with that?